# select all from matrix where column less than value

Tags: matlab

Is there a way in MATLAB to select from a matrix with a range of values in column `A(:,1)` where:

`B` = select from `A` where `A(:,1)<20070000`

Cannot find this logic anywhere

**EDIT**: I need to select these indicated rows from all columns of `A`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually to get all the rows can just do this:

```
B = A(A(:,1)<20070000,:)
```

Answer (score 1):

A straightforward solution looks like this:

```
rowInds = find(A(:,1)<2007000);
B = A(rowInds,:);
```

This will have the same number of columns as `A`. As Dan said it works without the `find`, using just the logical array to specify the rows directly.  Either way is fine.

The question has been clarified to requiring all columns, so the above is sufficient.